# Can't run Carrot2 workbench 3.11.0 on Windows (8 and 10)

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, carrot2

Java is installed (version 8).
My friend asked for help in this question but i can't find any answer.
If someone know how to run this program please tell me.

Windows 8 - 64-bit architecture, Windows 10 - 32-bit.

P.S. Sorry by my language (=

Comment: please, give more details on what errors you are getting.

Comment: On windows 10 it's a message "This application can't be run on this PC". I donw know what happen at friends device.

Comment: You need binaries compatible with your OS -- if it's 64-bit OS, you need 64-bit Workbench and 64-bit Java installed. If there are multiple JVMs installed on your system, you may need to directly specify the path to the JVM to be used through the workbench.ini file, see the [eclipse.ini syntax](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for details.